# Timpani notes for Bruckner's 7th Symphony

Tags: timpani

For Bruckner's 7th Symphony, the Timpani notes appear as:

---

- 1st movement (E major):

[image]

- 2nd movement (C# minor):

[image]

- 3rd movement (A minor):

[image]

- 4th movement (E major):

### [image]

The thing is, Bruckner uses only the tonic note of E for the first movement.  In the second movement, he uses C and G for the C major part instead of the tonic-dominant of C# and G#.  The third uses A and E which is awesome.  The fourth uses E as tonic, but uses C instead of B for the second note.  Why did Bruckner break the rules for the normal tonic-dominant tuning?

Comment: There are no rules..! There's *theory*.

Comment: That's right.  I've also checked the score for Beethoven's 8th in F dur, and the 1st and 3rd mvts require F-C which is good.  The 2nd mvt has no timpani at all (and has no development section too), and the 4th mvt requires F-F which is not tonic-dominant, but rather tonic-tonic.

Comment: The only movement that follows the standard tonic-dominant tuning is the 3rd mvt, in a-minor, as listed above.  However, in the c-minor part of the "scherzo" section, it re-tunes to C-G, and for the "trio" in F-major, it uses C-C.  The rest of the mvt uses the tonic-dominant of the home key, which is A-E.  In fact, I like how the timpani re-tunes its notes in order to match the key whenever there is a modulation.  However, the "trio" only has the dominant note and has no tonic.

Comment: Somehow I think the tonic unison tuning is fine, though, because Bruckner lets other instruments play the dominant note, instead.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya Where did you hear this rule about timpani needing to be tuned to tonic-dominant? I have never seen it in an orchestration text.

Comment: I don't know why you think the trio uses a "tonic unison tuning". There's no point in tuning two timps to the same pitch. It's just that only one timp is needed in the trio.

Comment: I am actually referring to the **first** movement for the tonic unison.  In third movement's trio, it's **dominant** unison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because those were the notes he wanted! (And there are some mid-movement re-tunings you haven't mentioned.)

The interesting part about the 2nd movement is not so much the timp. notes - C and G are absolutely conventional for music in C major -  but the fact that a movement nominally in C# minor includes a section in C major.

Comment: Yes.  Although the 3rd mvt uses A-E (tonic-dominant) for its original as it is in a-minor, it re-tunes into C-G for the c-minor section and C-C (not F-C!!!) for the F-major trio.

Comment: It seems unusual but inspiring that Bruckner tuned the timpani in unisons (E-E for 1st mvt, and C-C for trio of 3rd mvt), because even Beethoven sometimes tuned them in octaves! (Ex. F3-F2 for 8th IV and 9th II)